# Can't kill PHP script

Tags: php, linux, ssh

I am developing some PHP scripts on a Namecheap shared server. I accidentally made a loop which seems to go on indefinitely (or for a very long time), so now I am trying to kill it using SSH.

I have viewed a list of running processes with `top`, found the misbehaving PHP script, and tried to kill it with `kill`. However, after I kill it with this command, when I try using the `ps`, it is still running!

The result of the `ps`:

```
   PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
819520 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/php /my/php/file.php
```

I have tried killing the process over and over, but it just won't die!

The SSH is limited, so I can't use commands like `killall`. What do I do??!

Comment: Get the PID with `ps -ef` and then kill it with `kill -9 <pid>`

Comment: @fedorqui Wow thanks! Add it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To kill the process you can do the following:

- Get the PID with `ps -ef`
- kill it with `kill -9 <pid>`

A nice reference: [When should I use kill -9?](http://scofaq.aplawrence.com/FAQ_scotec6killminus9.html)

Just for fun, an example:

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 4156
$ ps -ef | grep slee[p]
me    4156  3501  0 10:34 pts/5    00:00:00 sleep 100
$ kill 4156
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 100
$ ps -ef | grep slee[p]
$
```

Comment: Thank you for the reference link!  In my case, I used "ps ux" and just plain kill <PID>.  I didn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'ps' (process status) to get the ID and then use 'kill' to stop it.

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl_kill.htm

Answer (score 0):

try this command. this will stop file from executing.

```
pkill -f /my/php/file.php
```